# How to pass data to controller's field from URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I know how to send data to controller's action method as parameter from URL. Here I wonder how can I send data from URL to controller's field?

```
public MyAwesomeController : Controller {
    public string SectionCode { get;set; }
}
```

and let's define Routes :

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name : "AwesomeRouter",
            url : "{code}/{action}",
            defaults: new {controller = "MyAwesome", action = "Index", /* What to do here?*/}
        );
```

I want SectionCode be filled with the {code} from URL. Is it possible to implement?

Comment: That's not how it works. Routing means fetching some URL and matching it with the appropriate *method* to invoke. You can declare `sectionCode` as a parameter to your action, then assign it to the `SectionCode` property. You can customize the controller factory or invoker to achieve your goal but I doubt it's worth the effort or the risks.

Comment: That's not the way it works. Routing matches a URL to a certain action. You could, however, create a custom attribute for your controller and have that search for the parameter and populate the property. That wouldn't be very elegant nor efficient, though.

Comment: It's bad design to have a property on your controller like this. Controllers have a request lifecycle (they are instantiated and disposed for each different request), so setting a property on the controller is pretty meaningless anyways. The action should accept whatever context is necessary for what's happening in the action, including in this case, your `code` value. Just accept it as an action param, and call it a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, you can create inherited class from basic Controller class and override OnActionExecuting method where you can read url, route or any form data and store them in session or directly fill any field you need. Then create an inherited class of your controller.

```
public class MyAwesomeController : MyControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //this.SectionCode is available populated here
        return View();
    }
}

public class MyControllerBase : Controller
{
    public string SectionCode
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        this.SectionCode = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["code"].ToString();
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Each time you hit any action in this controller using route definition you provided, field will be automatically populated. But when you will have more than one route defined they it could get easily into conflicts eg. when code will match to any controller name. Normal website should not work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your route should look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AwesomeRouter",
        url: "{code}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "MyAwesome", action = "Index" }
    );
```

The code should then be passed on to the action as a parameter. I am storing it in the view bag for explanation purposes:

```
public class MyAwesomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index(string code)
    {
        ViewBag.Code = code;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Using this URL then:

```
http://somehost/4567/Index
```

If you access the Viewbag property in your view:

```
@ViewBag.Code
```

You should see:

```
4567
```